# defining a root function with fortran in the "desolve" R package

Tags: r, fortran, ode

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a question regarding desolve, or point me to someone who could help.

I would like to keep one of my state variables below a certain value.

To do this I want to use a root function to determine when that theshold value is reached, and an event function to keep the state variable below that threshold.

However, I'm using fortran, and I can not find any examples in which a root function was used in compiled code.

In the package vignette (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/compiledCode.pdf) no root function is ever used; the event function is called based on pre-defined event times.

Is it possible to define and use a root function in fortran? Has anyone done this?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: I can't be of much help here but I know that R has a `.Fortran()` function for calling precompiled Fortran code.

Comment: What is a root function?